# SnakeYaml Alternatives for loading yaml in java

Tags: java, parsing, configuration, yaml, snakeyaml

I love using snakeyaml for reading configuration files currently. However, I would like to know if there exist any alternatives to it for loading yamls into java objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Jackson and YamlBeans for reading yamls. I'd recommend Jackson, because it appears to be more widespread and established: https://dzone.com/articles/read-yaml-in-java-with-jackson

Comment: Jackson's YAML extension uses SnakeYaml